# Pass string with quotes as input parameter to a SQL Server 2016 stored procedure using R Service

Tags: r, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016, quote

I am using SQL Server 2016 with R service. I am trying to create a stored procedure which I want to execute inserting text as parameter value.

```
e.g. exec test N'Hello World'
```

Generally it works fine but if input text which contain quotes it shows error.

Here my sample stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test] 
    (@param1 NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @sql = 'select = ''' + @param1 + ''';'

    PRINT(@sql)
    EXEC sp_execute_external_script 
               @language = N'R', 
               @script = N'data<-mynumbers 
                            OutputDataSet<-data.frame(data)',
               @params = N' @mynumbers nvarchar (max)',
               @mynumbers = @sql
 END
```

If I execute the procedure inserting text as parameter value which contain single or multiple quotes (e.g. don't , can't, Tom's), it shows an error:

```
exec test N' Don't do late making Tom's work '
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'ot'.
>
> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that single quote is a string identifier in SQL, e.g. single quotes "delimits" strings. If you want single quotes inside a string you need to "double" them. Your example would be:

```
exec test N' Don''t do late making Tom''s work '
```

Hope this helps.

Niels

Comment: Hi @Niels this would be tedious if the input text is a large  paragraph

Comment: @mzhasan: Sure, but this is the way SQL Server works. Where is the data coming from? If it is the database, it has already to be in the right format - otherwise, it couldn't be stored in a table. If it is from the outside, you should be able to programmatically format it.